# Content-Security-Policy (CSP) implementation in UI5

Tags: sapui5, content-security-policy

When implementing the `Content-Security-Policy` (`CSP`) in UI5 app, is it enough to specify the `CSP` in the HTML-bootstrapper (`index.html`):

```html
<meta content = "default-src https: 'self' https://….com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; child-src 'none'; object-src 'none';"
      http-equiv = "Content-Security-Policy" />
```

Or is it also mandatory to ensure that every single server response contains the `CSP`-header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OR first OR second

1. Content-Security-Policy HTTP response header is the [preferred](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#csp-header) mechanism for delivering a policy from a server to a client.
2. HTML [meta element](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#meta-element) with `http-equiv` attribute `Content-Security-Policy` has some **limitations** - not all directives supported there, and meta always works in **enforced mode** (no `Report-Only` feature).
   `*` It's strongly encouraged to place meta elements as early in the document as possible, because policies in meta elements are not applied to content which precedes them. In particular, note that resources fetched or prefetched using the Link HTTP response header field, and resources fetched or prefetched using link and script elements which precede a meta-delivered policy will not be blocked.

If you will use both - header and meta, these will [affect](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#multiple-policies) each other if differ.

Comment: Thanks for the info, if I'm going with the `CSP` over `HTTP response header`, then should I send this header for any response, even for a plain `JSON`-string or just for files (`*.js`, `*.mjs`, `*.css`, etc)?

Comment: CSP applies only to content which has `document` or `window` property (HTML, XML/XSLT). Only with content which can embeds script/styles/fonts/frames execute javascript - all these regulate by CSP directives.
Files `*.txt *.css *.js *.mjs .png .jpeg json *.woff *.ttf` etc. do not need CSP headers.

Comment: "Content which can embeds script/styles execute JavaScript", wait a moment, but `*.js`, `*.mjs`, and `*.css` actually meet this condition, or I didn't get you correctly?

Comment: `*.js, *.mjs` files can embed other JS/CSS but **only** when these get into HTML-page and executes there. Therefore HTML-document itself can apply CSP but files like `*.txt *.css *.js *.mjs json *.woff *.ttf` are delivered as plain text, `.png .jpeg` are delivered as specific format of bytes stream - those can't apply CSP. More correct wording: CSP covers `text/html` and `text/xml` MIME-types of content.